# wkhtmltopdf doesn't seem to fully support css3. Is there a build that does?

Tags: css, wkhtmltopdf

When using opacity and box-shadow, wkhtmltopdf produces a segmentation fault and complains "Painter not active." Where can I find out what version of Qwebkit wkhmtmlopdf is currently using and does anyone have experience compiling a binary of wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu that supports the latest css3 rendering?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a version of wkhtmlto(pdf/image) that supports CSS3 Columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925223/is-there-a-version-of-wkhtmltopdf-image-that-supports-css3-columns)